# SQL Multiple IF Statments (AR Roll Up)

Tags: sql, if-statement

How would i create a Sql command to follow the if statements below?

```
 if (Period  == 9) {9} else { 
     if (Age >= 94 )  {5} else {
     if (Age >= 63 )  {4} else { 
     if (Age >= 32 )  {3} else {
     if (Age >= 1 )   {2} else {
     if (Age >= -30 ) {1} else {
     if (Age < -30 ) {0} else {0}
    }}}}}}
```

AS 'CalcPeriod'

Comment: What Database Server?  Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, etc...

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case statement.  Below is a link to the usage of a case statement in TSQL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN (Period = 9) THEN
     9
  WHEN (Age >= 94) THEN
     5
  WHEN (Age >= 63) THEN
     4
  WHEN (Age >= 32) THEN
     3
  WHEN (Age >= 1) THEN
     2
  WHEN (Age >= -30) THEN
     1
  ELSE
     0
  END AS CalcPeriod
FROM SomeTableWithFieldsPeriodAndAge
```